# CSS Children applying a style to a parent

Tags: jquery, css, html

Given something like this:

```
.threadTitle {

}

.threadTitle.jeditable input {
}
```

When jeditable (jquery plugin) is active, the input appears, when it is not, the INPUT is not on the page. What I want to do is apply a style to .threadTitle only when the input is on the page?

Something like, .threadTitle When Input (.threadTitle.jeditable input) is visible {...}

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+style+parent

Answer (score 1):

<s>`.threadTitle:has(input)` will match an element with `.threadTitle` class if and only if it contains an input element. Not all browsers support it though.</s>

It is called `:contains` (I must have mixed it up with the jQuery `:has` selector); more importantly, it has apparently been [removed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors) from the CSS3 draft a while ago.